# Trouble solving a non-linear first order PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm struggling to find solution of the below equation:

$$u_x^3 - u_y = 0$$
$$u(x,0) = 2x^{3/2}$$

I was taught about method of characteristics and how to parametrize the equations with $s$ and $t$ to get ODE's but in this case I'm struggling with what will be the coefficients and overall how to proceed to get a solution.

Note: This problem is from Fritz John's and answer given is $u = 2x^{3/2}(1-27y)^{-1/2}$

Comment: Separation of variables is fine.

Comment: I am not sure I can use that method for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $0=F(\overbrace{x,y}^{\mathbf{x}},u,\overbrace{p,q}^{\nabla u}):=p^3-q$, the method of characteristic gives
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}&=\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}=3 p^2\\
\dot{y}&=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}=-1\\
\dot{u}&=p\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}+q\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}=3p^3-q\\
\dot{p}&=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}-p\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}=0\\
\dot{q}&=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}-q\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}=0.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

So the characteristics are lines
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
x&=x_0+3p_0^2 t\\
y&=y_0-t\\
u&=u_0+(3p_0^3-q_0)t\\
p&=p_0\\
q&=q_0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

From $F=0$ we have $q=p^3$ (and let's drop the suffix 0 from $p,q$ which are constant in $t$).  Let $y_0=0$, so $u_0=u(x_0,0)=2x_0^{3/2}$, $p=3x_0^{1/2}$, and $t=-y$.  Hence $x=x_0+3p^2t=x_0-27x_0y=(1-27y)x_0$, $x_0=x/(1-27y)$ and
\begin{align*}
u&=2x_0^{3/2}+2p^3t\\
&=2x_0^{3/2}+2(3x_0^{1/2})^3(-y)\\
&=2x_0^{3/2}(1-27y)\\
&=2\left(\frac{x}{1-27y}\right)^{3/2}(1-27y)\\
&=2x^{3/2}(1-27y)^{-1/2}.
\end{align*}